# Why do you use "much" when mentioning RAM?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, uncountable-nouns

> How much RAM do I need?

Why do I need to use *much* here? I was under the impression that if I'm mentioning anything countable, I should use *many*. You can always quantify RAM, so this seems very counterintuitive for me.

Comment: If you mean the animal, then you could try many, but you'd still be wrong. Unlike many sheep, it's many ramS.

Comment: @TaliaFord - unless it was the size of a single ungulate that you were concerned about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quantifying is not the same as counting.* You can say "2 litres of water", but that doesn't mean it's countable (it's not). Similarly, you can say "2 GB of RAM", but not "I need 2 RAMs in my phone": it's not countable. That's why you don't ask "how many RAMs do I need for this?", but rather:

> How **much** RAM do I need?

The word "GB" is obviously countable, though: written in full it would be "Gigabytes", abbreviated as GB (we tend to leave out plural endings when counting abbreviated units, cf. "2 l, 10 m, 7 kg").

---

*) I got to start with a capital q!

Comment: Quite a simple task, isn’t it, to start an answer with a q? ;-þ [Note how this comment, or the non-bracketed parts of it anyway, both starts and ends with a q!]

Comment: 'Quite' at the start of the sentence is quite different from placing an object or a subject or even a verb starting with a 'Q' there. Quintessential, this quagmire of what is known as 'the English language'. But still  +1 for starting with a Q, you both.

Comment: Writing *GBs* would be an error, since *GB* is not an abbreviation, but a symbol. The same happens with *l*, *m* or *kg*. Some symbols can even include non-Latin characters (e.g. *µm* for micrometre).

Comment: Quickly I thought I would eschew this implied challenge. Quite easy, I mused. Querulously, I raised my fingers to the keyboard, but to no avail. Quashed, my resolve fled. Quietly I tapped out my meager entry into the Q-stakes. Quelling my chagrin, I hit "add comment," and fled.

Comment: *humbly inclines heads*

Answer (score 1):

Think of RAM as being like a bowl of sand. You would say 'How much sand is there here?', but 'How many grains of sand are there here?'. Similarly 'how much RAM', but 'how many GB of RAM'.

Answer (score 0):

When you count something, you need some kind of unit to count with. Sometimes the thing itself provides a convenient unit. For example, if you need eggs, you generally need entire eggs at a time: you don't usually want to get only half of an egg, or only a quarter, or so on. So when you buy eggs, "egg" is your unit, and you ask how *many* eggs you want. Or you could group eggs into cartons, and ask how *many* cartons you want. But if I asked you for *an* egg, you'd hand me an egg.

But sometimes, the thing doesn't break down so easily. Water is a good example of this: you can break it down or build it up almost without limit. If I asked you for "a water," what would you give me? You might give me a glass full of water, or a pitcher full, or a big drum full: I haven't made it clear exactly how much I want. But if I specify some specific unit, then it becomes clear: if I ask you for "a liter of water," you know just how much to give me. If you don't know what units I need, you might ask me "how much" water I need, because it's not clear, and then I would give you some count of *units* of water, to make it clear.

RAM is closer to this second type. If I asked for "a RAM," it's not clear how much RAM to give me, and if I asked for "two RAMs" you wouldn't know what I meant. I need to ask for some specific unit, like "a gigabyte of RAM" before it's clear just what I need. Like with water, if you didn't know anything about the amount I needed, you could ask "how much" RAM I want, and then I'd give you a count of units: "4 gigabytes."

Comment: To carry the water analogy somewhat further, water is quantifiable as discrete units (molecules) but to do anything useful one needs many molecules.  Even when programming a machine with 128 bytes (not kbytes--individual bytes) of RAM, one seldom thinks in terms of individual bits.  With today's software routinely using many orders of magnitude more, bits of RAM are too small to be meaningful individually.